# Is it possible to style one React component using MUI/Bootsrap and another React component using Vanilla CSS

Tags: reactjs

So I'm making a react application and planning to create the dashboard using either Bootstrap or MUI and the landing page using vanilla CSS.  How do I make the dashboard only inherit css stylings from mui and vice versa, the landing page only inherit css stylings using vanilla css

I tried using css modules but to no avail.